# All font-size styles are being overridden, text is sized with browser default

Tags: css, firebug, font-size

Some text on a page I'm modifying is displaying with a computed size of 16px, which I understand is the default font size for most browsers. Firebug in FF 10 shows several font sizes which would apply to that element, but all are overridden (selector and value displayed with strikethrough).

Why would this happen? I assume any styles applied via scripting would appear in an element.style selector.
[image: Style panel]
[image: Computed panel]
[image: HTML panel]

Comment: can you add a link to the live page so we can inspect it?

Comment: Are some styles declared with `!important`? I've seen something similar happen before...

Comment: Is there a <font> tag in the code? That might mess you up.

Comment: The live page isn't available outside my network. But the image I posted contains the full Style panel content in Firebug-- that would show any '!important's or font tag styles, correct? Also, there are no 16px declarations; all of the overridden styles are 10px or 12px, which I think would rule out an !important.

Comment: Need to see more of the code.Can you screenshot some HTML?

Comment: It would also help to see the "computed" style panel as well.

Comment: Is this only happening if FF or is it all browsers? Check that you do not have a minimum font-size set in your browser options.

Comment: OK, just added a snippet of HTML (please excuse the badness, there's little of it I can modify) as well as the Text section of the Computed panel. This is happening on FF 10, IE 8 and Chrome 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe having a `table` element inside a `p` element is invalid HTML (you can check that by running through a validator).

I suspect this is the problem, and then the browsers are not letting the `table` inherit the `font` properties (due to the invalid structure) and thus are defaulting to the browser settings.

I think if you **get rid of the `p` as a wrapper** and make your css include:

```
#cajanoticias table {font-size: 10px}
```

you will solve your problem.